# How to sign transactions using metamask while developing in nodejs?

Tags: web3js, metamask, nodejs, web3-providers

I am developing an application in nodejs. I need to interact with my smart contract and also want to sign the transaction using metamask as I don't want to manage they keys. I copied the following code from the web3 docs but my id condition is never satisfied and "web3 is undefined" is printed in the conosle. On the other hand, if I enter web3 in my chromes console, web3 object with

> currentProvider: MetamaskInpageProvider

is returned.

```
const express = require('express');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const router = express.Router();


router.get('/',(req,res)=>{

    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Web3 found');
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
    } else {
        console.error('web3 was undefined');

    }
    res.send('hello');
})
```

Please help me to sign transactions using metamask while developing in nodejs.
P.S i tried to execute the above code with a timer to check race condition but still same result.

Comment: MetaMask will only work in the browser, it will not work in your backend.

Comment: `typeof web3...` should read `typeof Web3`.  Plus what Ismael said.